# KNP Bundle Menu Builder - Change route Locale

Tags: symfony, routes, locale, knpmenubundle

I want to use the **KNPMenuBundle** with the **MenuBuilder** in **Symfony2**.

The Original Link is:

```
<a href="{{ 
    path(app.request.get('_route'), 
    app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'}))
}}"></a>
```

But the Builder wont:

```
$menu->addChild('language', array('route' => 'routename'));
```

Comment: [http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/i18n.html](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/i18n.html)

Comment: The i18n features are only to translate labels. I want to add a language switcher to the menu - this is something different.

Comment: You are right. Why don't you merge the _locale parameter with your other route params using 'routeParameters' key ? I don't know if it works but you should try this maybe : $menu->addChild('language', array('route' => 'routename', 'routeParameters' => array('param' => $param, '_locale' => 'fr')));